# RazorPayment Integration using cordova Android

Tags: android, cordova, razor, payment, gateway

I am starting to implementating a RazorPayment Gateway in one of my cordova application. and I am using this 
https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova plugin. According to Razor Docs.

Step1: Payment is created when a user (the customer) fills up and submits the payment information and it is sent to the Razorpay API. : Successfully Implementaed

Step2:Authorized payment Details: Not Done

How can it possible using ajax. kindly tell me. event I completed my first step.

Can anyone share with me any knowledge how can I successfully completed this implementation.

Comment: can you provide the docs links ?

Comment: https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/checkout-form

Comment: kindly see at starting of doc.

Comment: The first code I am using with cordova plugin in which i found the payment page in mobile device.

Comment: where is the step 2 part there ?

Comment: Under Getting Started Blog.

Comment: steps are written like

Comment: To start accepting payments using Razorpay, you need:

API keys that can be generated through Razorpay's dashboard
Checkout form integrated in your website / app
Payment capturing process in your backend
The process of accepting payments from your end customers is as follows:

Users click on a pay button and are shown the Checkout Form
User fills his/her payment details and Authorizes the payment.
Checkout Form hands over to you the razorpay_payment_id
Your server side backend uses the razorpay_payment_id to capture the payment
You get the money in your bank account in T+3 days.

Comment: step 2 is kinda handled from the razorpay side i believe after reading the docs. you don't have to do anything for that

Comment: What you exactly tell to me? kindly suggest me more clearly plz

Comment: how can i implement in cordova mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

After successful step 1:
you will get a [token] from razorpay.

Send the [token] to your server via ajax and save it in database.

The step 2: is done via the server using their SDK in php, java, etc. using the [token]stored in database.

usually step 2 is done with background jobs by the server.

Hope this helps